# An unexpected error in pycharm has happened

Tags: pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, anaconda3

First, sorry for the bad english, i am not a native speaker...

I am trying to use anaconda in pycharm and wsl2. Now i have already set wsl2 up and download anaconda3 in wsl.

However, when i trying to add python interpreter in pycharm , i failed.

I clicked the 'Add New Interpreter ' , then 'On WSL'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiB8i.jpg)

I choose Conda Environment in WSL configuration, and clicked CREATE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQKWn.png)

And then , it goes an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyFXj.png)

I trying to choose to create  new enviroment , but also failed

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message. Share all details **in text form**, not hidden in screenshots